# How do I center all elements in the body of my page without applying the center format to text?

Tags: html, css

I want to center all elements in the body of my page, without applying the center format to paragraphs. For example, I want my paragraphs to be left aligned, but as a whole, centered in the window of the webpage.

I tried doing

```
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <p></p>
        <img>
    </div>
</body>
```

But while this centers all elements in the body on the page, it also forces center align within the paragraphs.

Comment: what kind of browser are you using? some browser have their own built in support for debugging CSS, why dont you try experimenting with it

Comment: Signature is removed, Please refer the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

Add some CSS for the `p` elements.

```
p {
   text-align: left;
}
```

You should be using `margin: 0 auto` to center block level elements. This also has the advantage of not changing inline centering.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I added this in <style type="text/css"> but it is just aligning the paragraphs to the left of the page (in addition to apply left-align within the paragraphs). 

any way to keep the left-align within the paragraphs, but center the paragraphs in the center of the page?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what width your main content will be the you can use margin:auto; similar to:

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="main">
    <p>hello world</p>
    <img>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body { 
    width: 200px;
    margin:auto;
}
.main {
    align: right;
    background:#eee;
}
```

or play with this: http://jsfiddle.net/MEDBF/

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you need here:

http://jsfiddle.net/W3pae/1/

centered div, paragraph left, image left

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could help you.
http://andrewpeace.com/css-center-screen-div.html

Comment: Dead link, doesn't load.